# Can't Import a file in different directory using Python

Tags: python

I have a python module at `/home/amit/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/nbsearch` named **neighbourhoodsearch.py**. I have included a class in this file in another module at `/home/amit/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/controller` named **nbsearch_controller.py**.

```
from neighbourhoodsearch import NeighbourhoodSearch
```

I have added the path `/home/amit/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/nbsearch` to PYTHONPATH using `sys.path.append` and added a file **__init__.py** in all the folders in the path. But still when I run the file nbsearch_controller.py, it says

```
ImportError: No module named neighbourhoodsearch
```

Comment: Having `__init__.py` files in `nbsearch` and `controller` folders and adding `nbsearch` to the path with `sys.path.append("/home/amit/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/nbsearch")` should be enough.

Comment: Why won't it work? I have checked the file/folder names also. Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple things:

- triple-check for typos in the path you give
- print `sys.path` before your problematic `import` and make sure that your path is really there
- remove `.pyc` files in your directory structure if you have some
- check the result of `os.path.isfile("/home/amit/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/nbsearch/neighbourhoodsearch.py")` (it should return `True`)
- check that you have "read" rights on your Python files

Answer (score -1):

See this question: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

You have the **init**.py file, so you should be good.